# Rust - How to initialize array of structs containing HashSet field?

Tags: arrays, rust, hashset

I have `Instance` struct with `HashSet` field for storing nonordered numbers with easy removing and adding with duplicates control.

Then there is another struct called `Matrix`, which holds an two-dimensional array of `Instance` struct.

I create the `new()` method in trait for `Instance` to use in array initialization, but using this method gives error during compilation, saying that `HashSet` does not implement the `Copy` trait.

Here is the code:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use std::collections::HashSet;

struct Instance {
    ids: HashSet<u8>,
    value: u8,
}

trait IsInstance {
    fn new() -> Instance;
}

impl IsInstance for Instance {
    fn new() -> Instance {
        Instance {
            ids: [1, 2, 3, 5].iter().cloned().collect(),
            value: 0,
        }
    }
}

/*
Line below is commented due to error:

error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
  --> src/main.rs:26:6
   |
5  |     ids: HashSet,
   |     ---------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
...
26 | impl Copy for Instance {}
   |      ^^^^

*/
//impl Copy for Instance {}

impl Clone for Instance {
    fn clone(&self) -> Instance {
        Instance {
            ids: self.ids,
            value: self.value,
        }
    }
}

struct Matrix {
    instances: [[Instance; 4]; 4],
    status: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Matrix {
        instances: [[Instance::new(); 4]; 4],
        status: 0,
    };
}
```

Compiling this gives error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.ids` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:42:18
   |
42 |             ids: self.ids, 
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.ids` has type `std::collections::HashSet<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Instance: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:60:22
   |
60 |         instances : [[Instance::new(); 4]; 4],
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `Instance`
   |
   = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Instance; 4]: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:60:21
   |
60 |         instances : [[Instance::new(); 4]; 4],
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `[Instance; 4]`
   |
   = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

Is there any way to properly initialize this array? I clearly missed something, but didn't find `HashSet` copy implementation working with arrays. Maybe there is another way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I clearly missed something, but didn't find `HashSet` copy implementation working with arrays.

That's because there isn't one! `Copy` means that a type is copyable bit-for-bit. That cannot be the case of a type like `HashSet<T>`. However what `HashSet<T>` is is default-initializable. Combine with the fact that arrays (under 32 elements for now) are also default-initializable, you can use the following:

```rust
let mut m = Matrix {
    instances: Default::default(),
    status: 0,
};
```

if you add

```rust
impl Default for Instance {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4fc7cb6317a11afd66bf382130954e21))

Comment: Oh, this is great and works in my case. Thanks! The obvious question is is there a method for arrays with more than 32 elements? It is just me being curious :)

Comment: @Vix no. There may eventually be once const generic are stable: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61415